# UITextField with UIPickerView keyboard bug

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I just want to ask if how can I prevent keyboard popping out when it's pressing the `UITextField`? I have a `UITextField` and `UIPickerView` if I press the `UITextField` for the first time it's fine, it's showing the `UIPickerView` but then after i select in the `UIPickerView` then press the textfield again, instead of showing the `UIPickerView` again it shows the keyboard? I have this method on my `UITextField` when you click it it shows the `UIPickerView`:

```
- (IBAction)clickText:(id)sender
{
    int tag = [(UITextField*)sender tag];
    self.myPicker.hidden = NO;
    selectedTable = tag;
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    float yy = 10;
    switch (tag) {
        case 0: yy = self.txtLeasename.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
            break;
        case 1: yy = self.txtFeet.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
            break;
        case 2: yy = self.txtInches.frame.origin.y + self.myPicker.frame.size.height;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

How can i fix this kind of bug? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this Method and don't forget to assign the textfield.delegate to your controller

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Check if the given textfield is your textfield with the date picker.
    if (textField.tag == 99) {
       // Then add your picker to your view
       UIDatePicker *pv = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMakeZero];
       [self.view addSubview:pv]; 

       // And return NO
       return NO; // Return NO prevents your Textfield from showing the Keyboard
    }

    return YES;

}
```

This should work for you:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    int tag = textField.tag;
    selectedTable = tag;
    float yy = 10;

    switch (tag) {
        case 0: 
            self.myPicker.hidden = NO;
            return NO;

        case 1:
            self.myPicker.hidden = NO;
            return NO;

        case 2:
            self.myPicker.hidden = NO;
            return NO;

        default:
            self.myPicker.hidden = YES;
            return YES;

        }        
}
```

Comment: this affects all of my textfield.. how can i implement this on a single textfield? or 2 maybe?

Comment: This function is a delegate function of UITextField. It is called whenever a UITextField in your ViewController should begin editing. (Like signature says). So that's why you have to check if the given textfield is the textfield you want. In my answer above I'm doing it with the `tag` attribute. If you want to affect 2 textfields you can extend the `if` statement. Maybe : `if (textField.tag == 99 || textField.tag == 12)`.

Comment: i got a error on CGRectMakeZero, "Use of undeclared indentifier" ? how can i fix this. sorry im just new on objective-c

Comment: sorry my fault. This is correct `CGRectMake(CGRectZero)`

Comment: Ok this is it: `[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`

Comment: there's no error on codes now, but now even the pickerview is not showing

Comment: you have to change my code above to your needs. It was just an example. I will edit my answer to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

[UITextField Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView)

```
inputView
The custom input view to display when the text field becomes the first responder.

@property(readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView
Discussion
If the value in this property is nil, the text field displays the standard system keyboard when it becomes first responder. Assigning a custom view to this property causes that view to be presented instead.

The default value of this property is nil.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared In
UITextField.h
```

So just set the proper `inputView` for your `UITextField` in `viewDidLoad` or else where. Something like:

```
self.myTextField.inputView = self.myPicker
```